# Darle formato específico a un número en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Debo forzar este cambio ya que en idioma español al utilizar la función:

```
Intl.NumberFormat().format();
```

Para cambio de divisa, el formato me lo da: 13.263,49 cuando debe ser 13,263.49, por otro lado si cambio el idioma en Chrome a español-Latinoamerica lo da correctamente.

Esto es para que usuarios no tengan que entrar a la configuración y hagan el cambio, algunos no saben ni hacer eso. Espero puedan apoyarme

Comment: ¿Quieres que TODO Chrome se muestre en otro idioma? ¿O cuál es tu objetivo específico?

Comment: Cambiar el idioma del navegador para afectar a un formato numérico sería el equivalente de comprarte otra casa porque el suelo está sucio. ¿No crees que sería más eficiente cambiarle mejor el formato al número que te devuelve la función?

Comment: Si entro a tu pagina y me venis con estos problemas, me daria ganas de matarte.. obviando ese problema, la pregunta es correcta..

Comment: Gracias, descubrí que algunas versiones de Chrome están con idioma español (así solo) y mi procedimiento de cambio de divisa lo hace correcto cuando Chrome tiene como idioma español-Latinoamerica. Mi intención es que a nivel código force el idioma del navegador al que se necesita. Para que los usuarios no tengan que hacerlo manualmente porque mucho no saben ni hacer eso. PHPMyguel estoy valorando la opción de traerme al código el idioma del navegador y condicionar el cambio de divisa, pero remotamente imagine podría hacerse algo similar.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente índica el formato de idioma que deseas pasándole como parámetro el código a [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)

```js
var numero = 13263.49;
var texto = Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(numero);
console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Perfecto, funcionando al 100% no importa el idioma del navegador.

Comment: Utilizando el seguimiento de este tema, utilizando la función:

var texto = Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(numero);
convierte perfectamente a pesos MXN, pero tiene un detalle, cuando el decimal cae en 0 no lo aparece, es decir: 1,491.3

Cuando el redondeo no cae el decimal en 0 lo marca perfectamente: 1,491.32. Alguien sabe por que?

Comment: Cuando le das un código de idioma a la función `NumberFormat` estás usando un formato predefinido, en este caso español latinoamerica, y este no conserva los ceros a la derecha.  Si quieres mostrar siempre 2 decimales puedes pasarle la opción `minimumFractionDigits`.  Te recomiendo la documentación de esta función (el link ahí en mi respuesta), tiene varias opciones que te permiten controlar como será convertido a texto el número.